# ng2-toastr with system js not working

Tags: angular, plugins, systemjs

I'm trying to integrate [ng2-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr).
Below is the import in the app.module.js

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr';


imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,        
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ToastModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

also in the service i'm import and using the ToastManager service.In **systemjs.config** i have added the plugin entry

**under map**

```
'ng2-toastr': 'npm:ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js'
```

**under packages:**

```
'ng2-toastr': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
```

But i'm getting the error:

> Error: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined

I have installed and used the plugin in a demo app which does not use systemjs.But my application uses systemjs.

Not sure how to solve this.Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: import like this import {ToastModule} from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

Comment: tried that.i change to 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr' and accordingly changed systemjs entries.Dint work.

Comment: If you are using angular-cli you do not need to include 'node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js'